# Gigabit Ethernet карта Mac-совместимая

Tags: mac, сеть, eth0

Господа!

Подскажите пожалуйста гигабитную ethernet карту с 2 и более портами, совместимую с Mac 10.6 и выше, для установки в Mac Pro и Bizon PC.

Hardware Compatibility List на сайте Apple что то не могу найти. Буду признателен за ссылку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например

```
Sonnet Presto Gigabit Ethernet Server 2-Port PCIe Card OS X
```

Answer (score 0):

Что-то я не припомню выпускаемых сейчас двухпортовых (или более) карт для обычных компов.
Для серверов есть.

Comment: Я видел на Мак Про такую карту, вот и хочу узнать какая. Так возьмешь на "авось", а на маке не заработает...

Comment: не факт что это отдельная карта - есть материнки с двухпортовыми встроенными картами.  Я думаю под МакОсью пойдет любая карта, т.к. драйверов и в системе и от производителей для этой ОС есть много